# Additional custom Omega breakpoint CSS files

Tags: 7, theming

I'm looking to add my own custom wide, normal and narrow CSS files additional to the ones Omega will already look for. I'm aware that by default it'll already search for

YOURSUBTHEME-alpha-default-wide.css

etc

But I was wondering is there anywhere/anything I can set that will allow me to ask it to look for another set of wide, normal and narrow CSS files?

eg: custom-alpha-default-wide.css

And have these automatically be included within the default breakpoint configuration?

I know that I could manually declare all the stylesheets in the .info file, and then copy the media queries into each applicable CSS sheet, however I'm interested to know if it can be done by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it, you can do it like this in the template.php file of your theme

```
// Adds the Delta responsive stylesheets
$theme = alpha_get_theme();
$layouts = $theme->grids['alpha_default']['layouts'];
$keys = array_keys($layouts);
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/css/CUSTOM-' . $keys[$i] . '.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'weight' => (120 - $i), 'media' => $layouts[$keys[$i]]['media']));
}
```

This will now look for your own CSS files called

- /css/CUSTOM-narrow.css
- /css/CUSTOM-normal.css
- /css/CUSTOM-wide.css

And call them in the same way your other breakpoints are called, and if you're looking for the ability to add your own separate stylesheets separate to the normal ones, this'll do it.